# how to prove the following for first order taylor's approximation?

Tags: taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

we have the taylor approximation as follows

$$f(x) = f(\bar x) + \nabla f(\bar x)(x − \bar x) + o(\|x − \bar x\|)$$

How to prove this?

If f is continuous over $[\bar x, x]$ and differentiable over $(\bar x, x)$, then:

$$f(x) = f(\bar x) + \nabla f(z)(x − \bar x),
  \; \text{for some} \; z \in [\bar x, x]$$

Comment: Umm, mean value theorem?

Comment: i guess so, can you please be elaborate?

Comment: Apply the mean value theorem to $\phi(t) = f(t x_2+(1-t)x_1)$.

Comment: I couldn't get to the answer, can you please provide an answer?

Comment: Apply the mean value theorem to the function in my previous comment.

Comment: $$ \nabla f(x+t(x-\bar x))(x − \bar x) = f(x) - f(\bar x)$$ I got to this by applying mean value theorem between t =0 and t = 1

Comment: Which would suggest that you set $z$ to what???

Comment: $$ z = x + t(x−x¯)$$ but how do I go further?

Comment: I'm confused. Is that not what you are trying to prove?

Comment: $$ \text{oh! shit I got lost in }  o(\|x − \bar x\|), \text{ my bad, thanks}$$